# Store log in to database using ActiveMq, Spring, JMS and Camel

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, activemq-classic

I am trying to develop a logging application. I am trying to store the log in DB. ONe way is;
There will be a listener on other end that will listen the queue and if any message is there; it will pick it and put it in to database.

I am using ActiveMQ, Spring, log4j for this purpose.

I found one article. It is suggesting that You need not require Message Listener in Spring if 
"Eliminate the Listener class by using Apache Camel within ActiveMQ and have Camel save the data directly to the database from within ActiveMQ."

How to achieve this.

http://syntx.io/asynchronous-logging-using-log4j-activemq-and-spring/

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You still need something that reads from the queue be it a `MessageListener`, a Spring `JmsTemplate` or `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` there needs to be something that reads from the queue. A listener works fine do you really want and need to introduce a big thing like Apache Camel for this (quite simple) requirement?

Comment: However, I am following the link but not be able to run the progrm. How to run the program mentioned in the link. Please guide me. Thanks for your time.